# Run cmd from a given folder inside PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, cmd

Is there any possibility to run a cmd command from a different folder then the script home location (e.g. C:\ScriptHome)?

I mean e.g.

```
Cmd /C "C:\Test\test.exe"
```

- but this exe should be called from e.g. "C:\RunTestExeHere"

Basically, it can be done in pure cmd, like `cd "C:\RunTestExeHere"` and after

```
C:\RunTestExeHere>C:\Test\test.exe
```

- but can it be done in powershell?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to sandwich your external command between `Push-Location` and `Pop-Location` commands.

A simple example:

```
Push-Location -EA Stop C:\  # You'd use C:\RunTestExeHere instead
cmd /c dir                  # You'd use & "C:\Test\test.exe" instead
Pop-Location
```

Another option (the invocation syntax is less convenient):

```
Start-Process -Wait -NoNewWindow cmd -ArgumentList /c, dir -WorkingDirectory C:\
```